# Https with TLS 1.2 in Xamarin

Tags: ssl, xamarin

I'm using HttpClient in Xamarin to request to https with TLS 1.2 and I got the error as below;

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ProcessAlert (AlertLevel alertLevel, AlertDescription alertDesc) [0x00013] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:574 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x000d0] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:376 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) [0x00035] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:425 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:99 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:969 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[System.Net.WebResponse].InnerInvoke (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, System.Func`2 endMethod, IAsyncResult l) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/TaskFactory_T.cs:473 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.WebResponse].GetResult () [0x00034] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/ConfiguredTaskAwaitable_T.cs:62 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002d0] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:338 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00034] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/ConfiguredTaskAwaitable_T.cs:62 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:273 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00049] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/Task.cs:709 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/Task.cs:679 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].get_Result () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/Task_T.cs:48 
  at Cucumber.ViewModels.LoginViewModel+<ExecuteLoginCommand>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00144] in /Users/bachpx1/FSBProjects/FsoftInternalNews/cucumber/xamarin_form/Cucumber/Cucumber.Shared/ViewModels/LoginViewModel.cs:94 
 --> (Inner exception 0) System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.ProcessAlert (AlertLevel alertLevel, AlertDescription alertDesc) [0x00013] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:574 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x000d0] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:376 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (IAsyncResult result) [0x00035] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:425 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:99 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0005e] in ///Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/8.9.1.3/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:969 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[System.Net.WebResponse].InnerInvoke (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1 tcs, System.Func`2 endMethod, IAsyncResult l) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading.Tasks/TaskFactory_T.cs:473 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.WebResponse].GetResult () [0x00034] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/ConfiguredTaskAwaitable_T.cs:62 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler+<SendAsync>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x002d0] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClientHandler.cs:338 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:62 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00034] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.CompilerServices/ConfiguredTaskAwaitable_T.cs:62 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient+<SendAsyncWorker>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpClient.cs:273
```

**Do anyone know how to fix this issue. I have heard is Xamarin are errors with TLS in Mono 2.0.**
**Many thanks**

Comment: as far as I can find mono does not yet support tls 1.1 or 1.2
which is problematic since ssl and tls1.0 are not PCI compliant

Comment: Yeah, looks like it's still not done yet :( https://trello.com/c/PvUaV89u/16-tls-stack

Answer (score 6):

TLS is [not yet fully implemented](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2015/Aug-27.html) in Mono. That means your HTTPS requests may fail where they would not when running your .NET app on Windows.

## Xamarin Deployment

Since you are using Xamarin, you can use [ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient) which is a wrapper around the native iOS / Android networking libraries.

> Android, Mac and iOS users can get the latest TLS for HTTP workloads
>   using ModernHttpClient. Mac/iOS users can use the built-in
>   CFNetworkHandler as well.

## Linux/Mac Deployment

If you are deploying Mono on Linux/Mac (without Xamarin), you'll need to find a workaround for the lack of TLS support.

There are 2 possible workarounds that come to mind:

#### Use a Custom TLS Implementation

Try using [juhovh/AaltoTLS](https://github.com/juhovh/AaltoTLS), which is an implementation of the SSL/TLS network protocol written completely using C# and standard cryptographic libraries of .NET where relevant. It will take care of the TLS decryption/encryption and won't use the built-in lacking Mono implementation.

#### Implement a TLS Proxy

Build a **TLS Proxy** that will do the TLS heavy-lifting for you -- you'll configure it as an HTTP proxy for your HTTP requests in Mono, it will receive them, and query the target server via HTTPS, handling the encryption and decryption for the Mono app.

**Workflow:**

Mono App -> HttpClient sends HTTP request via TLS Proxy -> TLS Proxy converts HTTP request to HTTPS and sends it to target server -> TLS Proxy receives response -> TLS Proxy sends back response to HttpClient in HTTP format

Example code in Node.js for the TLS Proxy workaround using [nodejitsu/node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy):

```
// Modules
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

// Proxy server options
var options = {secure: true}; // Validate remote SSL certificates

// Create a proxy server with custom application logic
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer(options);

// Handle errors gracefully
proxy.on('error', function(e) {
    // Log to console
    console.log(e);
});

// Create server and define custom logic
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // URL provided?
    if (req.url) { 
        // Convert to HTTPS
        req.url = req.url.replace('http://', 'https://');
    }

    // Get remote host from headers (and force HTTPS)
    var target = 'https://' + req.headers.host;

    // Proxy the request (target is the server to pass the request on to)
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: target });
});

// Proxy port
var port = 8080;

// Start listening for requests from clients
server.listen(port);

// Log the port number
console.log('proxy.port: ' + port);
```

Comment: A useful [link](http://kerry.lothrop.de/httpclient-flavors/) on how to swap default mono httpclienthandler.

Comment: HttpClientHandler is useful but only for those using Mono to develop for iOS/Android.

Answer (score 1):

Found this error at Release build, yet not in Debug build.

For Xamarin + VS, TLS 1.2 can be set in Android Project Properties (right click on your Android Project > Properties on  bottom) > Android Options > scroll to bottom, click Advance > bottom, SSL/TLS Implementations. There you found Native TLS 1.2+.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a generic cross-platform Xamarin solution for this.

Xamarin has an option to support TLS 1.2 for iOS9 with App Transport Security ( https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/ ) :

> Any connection made with NSUrlConnection, CFUrl or NSUrlSession will
>   use ATS by default in apps built for iOS 9 and OS X 10.11 (El
>   Capitan).
>   ATS will enforce the following requirements for all internet
>   connections: All connection ciphers must be using forward secrecy. The
>   Transport Layer Security (TLS) protocol must be version 1.2 or
>   greater. At least a SHA256 fingerprint with either a 2048 bit or
>   greater RSA key, or a 256 bit or greater Elliptic-Curve (ECC) key must
>   be used for all certificates.

There is a community push to fill this gap since April 2014 at https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/144858-xamarin-platform-suggestions/suggestions/5758129-implement-tls-1-2 .

Answer (score 0):

Currently TLS 1.2 is supported by Mono [release](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.8.0/) 4.8.0