# Xamarin Android HttpClient Error when use from a Class

Tags: ssl, xamarin.android, httpclient

I have the following code that errors out when going to site what has SSL. (Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)  Their SSL cert is valid.  When the HttpClient code is called directly there is not issue. What is wrong with my code?

```
 Uri uri =new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
  using (HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClientClass())
   {
       var tt = await httpclient.GetAsync(uri);
       string tx = await tt.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       Log.Info(TAG, tx);
    }




 public class HttpClientClass : HttpClient
  {
     private HttpClient _httpclient = null;
     private HttpClientHandler messagehandler = new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler();

     public  HttpClientClass()
     {
       _httpclient = new HttpClient(messagehandler);
      }
   }
```

Code with No Problem

```
Uri uri =new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
  using (HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient())
   {
       var tt = await httpclient.GetAsync(uri);
       string tx = await tt.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
       Log.Info(TAG, tx);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Https with TLS 1.2 in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29813601/https-with-tls-1-2-in-xamarin)
here is the solution. Add Nuget modernhttpclient by Paul Betts and use below. That should work within class or not.

```
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
            {
                var tt = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
                string tx = await tt.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //Log.Info(TAG, tx);
            }
```

Comment: The issue is that the "inside class" example does not work but works when the httpclient is called directly.  The purpose of "inside class" is so that I can change to  different handler in one place rather then doing a find and replace all over the Project.

Comment: when the httpclient is called directly doesn't work for me either. Are you using XFroms or Classic? Where do you call this code from? Activity or PCL?

Comment: I am using Xamarin Android classic and I just put in a class file.

Comment: that is what I did and put it in my activity in button click. httpclient alone didn't work for me. I am using VS simulator API 23. Any other site I try for example Uri uri = new Uri("https://ottawa.energate.ca"); works. Here is the suggestion. Can you try the Uri I mentioned now with and without class ans let know how it worked.

Comment: If the uri is a non SSL it would work with both method.   I have no problem my original Uri if it is used directly in the Activity.  BTW, I am testing on  actual Android device,  KitKat 4.4, Lolipop 5 and Marshmallow 6.0, all exhibiting the same error message when used with "Inside Class".

Comment: ottawa.energate.ca is SSL. The comments editor just cut this from my comment for some reason and it cuts it from facebook URI later in my comment. Can you please test on ANY "https" web site and tell what you see. for example "https://www.facebook.com/" Just use HTTPS, editor cuts it

Comment: I am not sure if this is problem with my code or due to the type of service  I am requesting.   If I use Facebook graph Uri uri = new Uri("http://graph.facebook.com/6708787004");   the "inside class: errors {"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"HYy5b5uHCtX"}}
 but for the direct it just hangs there without error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127509/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-albertk).