# SSL Trust Issue from Xamarin

Tags: android, ssl, xamarin, httpclient

I'm working on a cross-platform application using Xamarin Native with a PCL. Long story short, the PCL contains a class that makes calls to a RESTful web service (Microsoft's Web API 2) and returns data to the mobile app. Our team has tested our app successfully in QA and Stage environments, but when changing the url to our production server, we get the following error:

Error: TrustFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)

The only differences I am aware of between production and the other environments is that the production URL hits a load balancer and there are two servers (prod1 and prod 2) behind the load balancer. From what I understand the same certificate is used (wildcard on the domain name), and same configs all around.

Literally everything works fine when pointing to QA and Stage, but Prod fails.

Interestingly enough, I can call anonymous GET methods from the Web API with success in the following situations:

1. From Postman on my dev machine
2. From unit tests that use the PCL on my dev machine
3. From a web browser on my dev machine
4. From the web browser on my mobile device.

It ONLY fails when running the code and accessing the API through the PCL on the mobile app.

UPDATE: I was informed that the production load balancer uses the same certificate. However, SSL cert is installed only on the load balancer, and not on the underlying servers. Something about SSL offloading? I don't know exactly how it works, but apparently the requests from load balancer to underlying server do not use SSL, just from load balancer to requester.

Comment: Similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40445255/xamarin-android-httpclient-error-when-use-from-a-class/40446999#40446999 I think it may be related to either load balancer or cert name. If cert is the same its name will match either with your Staging or Production server. What is the server URI?

Comment: **Assuming** you are not using the `AndroidClientHandler` for your HttpClient handler and not on version `Cycle 8 SR 0`+? https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44708

Comment: Thanks! I ran the url through https://www.wormly.com/test_ssl. Interestingly enough it told me there was a trust issue. "The certificate was issued by Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2, which is not a trusted authority. This is most likely because the servers' certificate chain is not installed correctly." I think this means something on the server needs to be set up for the CA chain? Is that correct?

Comment: Another update. I can override the error (for now) by returning true in the ServerCertificateValidationCallback. Obviously this is not a complete solution, but allows us to continue testing in this environment. It seems the app does not trust the CA, but the browser on the same device does??